# Flutter: How to make an object accessible to other widgets without passing

Tags: android, flutter, dart, riverpod

I am building an application focusing on reminders. From the list of reminders present on the homepage, a `reminderSection` widget is shown. The `reminderSection` has an attribute `thisReminder`. I want `thisReminder` to be accessible to all of the descendant widgets of `thisReminder`. So that they can use `thisReminder` and I don't have to pass it around.

What I've done is use `Riverpod`. I wrapped `myApp` with `ProviderScope` and defined the provider in the `initState` of `reminderSection` like this:

`final thisReminderProvider = Provider<Reminder>((ref) => widget.thisReminder);`

And I want to use it in another widget, for example, `reminderFormSection` which is just where the title and dateTime of the reminder is set. I did the necessary changes to the class definition and tried accessing the provider in the `initState` like this:

```
class ReminderFormSection extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {

  const ReminderFormSection({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  ConsumerState<ReminderFormSection> createState() => _ReminderFormSectionState();
}

class _ReminderFormSectionState extends ConsumerState<ReminderFormSection> {
  late Reminder thisReminder;

  @override
  void initState() {

    thisReminder = ref.read(thisReminderProvider);
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the error that `thisReminderProvider` is `undefined`. I think I need to define the provider outside the class and the `reminderSection` file's path to the `reminderFormSection` file. But how do I define the provider outside the class if the object I want to provide is a class attribute?

Comment: Please provide the code where the provider is defined, it is unclear where its value is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for it to be able to change the reminder that is selected from one part of your code, and be able to get the current value in another widget (`ReminderFormSection`).

**Providers shall always be global variables**. In your case, since you want to be able to change the state you shall use a "Notifier":

```dart
final reminderProvider = NotifierProvider<ReminderNotifier, Reminder?>(ReminderNotifier.new);

final class ReminderNotifier extends Notifier<Reminder?> {
  @override
  Reminder? build() {
    return null;
  }

  /// Function used to change the selected reminder, which will notify any widgets watching the Provider.
  void select(final Reminder reminder) {
    state = reminder;
  }
}
```

Wherever you are selecting the reminder, use the notifier of the provider:

```dart
final reminderNotifier = ref.read(reminderProvider.notifier);
// ...
reminderNotifier.select(reminder);
```

Then, in widgets where you want to access to the currently selected reminder, you shall **watch** the provided value.

```dart
class ReminderFormSection extends ConsumerWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WdigetRef ref) {
    final Reminder? reminder = ref.watch(reminderProvider);
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. One more question I have is that is there a way to get the value from the notifier or is just to select the value. Currently I have two objects, `thisReminder` whose data I got from `ref.read` while another object `thisReminderNotifier` to select the data. Do I need to have both of these in `ConsumerStatefulWidget` or I can get the reminder value from the notifier too?

Comment: Yes, you need both since they have separate responsibilities. Think of Notifier as a "service" object which is used to manipulate the value which is returned by a provider, however the underlying `state` (the provided value) is not exposed externally by the notifier, consequently you need to watch/read it separately as you did with `thisReminder`

Answer (score 0):

Declare your provider outside of your ReminderForm or ReminderFormState section

```
final myProvider = Provider<String>((_) => 'John Doe');

class MyProviderClient extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // watch your provider here
    final providerValue = ref.watch(myProvider);
    return Text(providerValue);
  }
}
```

if you have a ConsumerStatefulWidget

```
@override
  void initState() {
  var providerValue = ref.read(myProvider);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue lies with defining the provider within initState of reminderSection. Providers in Riverpod should be defined outside of widgets and accessed throughout the widget tree. Here's how to achieve this and make thisReminder accessible to all descendants:

1. Define the Provider Outside reminderSection:

Create a separate file (e.g., reminder_providers.dart) to house your providers.
Define thisReminderProvider as a global final variable:

```
// reminder_providers.dart
final thisReminderProvider = Provider<Reminder>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());
```

2. Pass thisReminder as an Argument:

Instead of using a provider within reminderSection, modify it to receive thisReminder as an argument in its constructor:

```
// reminder_section.dart
class ReminderSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final Reminder thisReminder;

  const ReminderSection({
    super.key,
    required this.thisReminder,
  });

  // ... rest of your widget implementation
}
```

3. Provide thisReminder in MyApp:

Wrap your MyApp with ProviderScope.
In the build method of MyApp, provide thisReminder using Provider.value:

```
// main.dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(
        // Access your reminder data here and pass it to ReminderSection
        thisReminder: Reminder(/* Initialize your reminder object */),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Reminder thisReminder;

  const MyApp({super.key, required this.thisReminder});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // ...
      home: ReminderSection(thisReminder: thisReminder),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, inside reminderFormSection, you can directly access thisReminder via the Consumer widget and the ref.watch method:

```
class ReminderFormSection extends ConsumerWidget {
const ReminderFormSection({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final thisReminder = ref.watch(thisReminderProvider);

    // Use thisReminder in your form section

    return // ...;
  }
}
```